# Display Annotations without Mapview

Tags: iphone, augmented-reality, mkmapview

I am doing  project related to  Augment reality.I have to display annotations on transparent background.
I have array  of latitude, longitude.

I search on net,almost all topics are related to  display on mapview.

Is it possible to show annotations  on uiview or transparent mapview.

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible assuming you want to overlay these annotations over a camera view. There is a good open source library,

http://www.mixare.org/

Note: This library isn't that great performance vise however it will serve the purpose. If you are making a project for high end clients then go for ARLab SDK.

http://www.arlab.com/

They have perfected Augmented reality very well.